# Select a sequence of a stream

Tags: java, arraylist, sequence, modulus

I have an ArrayList of elements with a timestamp.

Given an element of this array, I would like to select all the elements happing a certain time before and after that given element.

The problem is that this time stamp goes to 60 000 milisec and then start again from zero.

So if I would like to get all the elements happening, say 1000 milisec before and after the element with timestamp 59 999 I don't know how to do this.

I have been looking at the modulus operation but I don't seem able to make it work.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What is the simplest test-case that it failed on?

Comment: What is the type of the elements in the list and how would you determine their "happening" time?

Comment: The elements have a timestamp (int between 0-60000) and they are added to the ArrayList chronically.

Comment: So I tried:
    if (startSequenceTime <= (currentMessage.getTime() - BACKWARD_TIME) % 60000)  addMessage();

and

    if (currentMessage.getTime() >= (startSequenceTime + FORWARD_TIME) % 60000) addMessage();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<Integer> timestamps;
int target = 59999; // matches are from 58999 to 999 (wrapped around)
for (Integer timestamp : timestamps) {
    if (Math.abs(timestamp + 60000 - target) <= 1000 || Math.abs(timestamp - target) <= 1000) {
        // this timestamp is a match
    }
}
```

This code simply check twice - once each for roll-over and non-roll-over.

I've tested it and it works for "roll-under" as well - ie when the target is less than 1000 (so the range would be between 59000 + target and target)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be use a `SortedSet` instead of a `List` (if elements cannot be repeated).

Create a `Comparator` based on the timestamp field of your elements (if this is not already their natural order) and then use the `NavigableSet` features of the sorted set to retrieve the `lower`, `floor`, `ceiling` or `higher` elements with reference to another element.

If you have repeated elements, and you definetively need to use a `List`, I would first sort the `List` with `Collections.sort` using my `Comparator` and the I would iterate over the list looking for the first element lower/higher than my reference timestamp. And using the method `List.sublist` I would extract all the elements front the list that satisfy the criteria.

Both `Date` and `Calendar` have methods named before and after that can help you determine if a given timestamp is before or after some refrence time. If you want to know how many milliseconds before or after you simply subtract the number of millisecond of one of the timestamp from the other.